# Card Game in Java: Creating a "hand of cards"

Tags: java

I would like to first say that this is not homework, but a pet project that I am working on in Java to better understand a complete Java program, and will hopefully be my first attempt at making my own GUI.

That aside, I have a question about creating a hand of cards from my current code. As it stands, I have a main class called `DummyRummy`, a class for creating cards, a class that creates a standard deck of cards (which includes Jokers and "shuffles" the deck when a new deck is created), and a `PlayerHands` class. I am strictly working with `ArrayList`s for all of the code, and the `PlayersHands` class should return two `ArrayList`s that will be used. However, when I try to call the `PlayerHands()` method in the `public static void main()`, `PlayerHands` cannot be located for some reason... Here is the code for `PlayerHands`:

```
package dummyrummy;
public class PlayerHands {
    private Card[] playerOneCards;
    private Card[] playerTwoCards;
    private int[] value;

    PlayerHands(deck d, int round)
    {
        value = new int[round+3];
        playerOneCards = new Card[round+2];
        playerTwoCards = new Card[round+2];
               //(round+2) is the handsize at any given time
        for (int x=0; x<round+3; x++)
        {
        playerOneCards[x] = d.drawFromDeck(); //fills up one hand.
        playerTwoCards[x] = d.drawFromDeck(); //fills up second hand.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `DummyRummy` class.

```
package dummyrummy;
import java.util.*;
public class DummyRummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        deck testDeck;
        testDeck = new deck();

        System.out.println(testDeck.getTotalCards());
        System.out.println(testDeck.getClass());
        int round = 1;
        PlayerHands(testDeck, round); //This is where the error is occurring        
        }//End of arguments
    }//End of DummyRummy class
```

Here is the `Card` class:

```
package dummyrummy;
public class Card
{
    private short rank, suit;
    private static String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Joker"    };
    private static String[] ranks = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    private static String[] jokers = {"Joker", "Joker"};
    private static String[] ranks2 = {"0", "0"};
    public static String rankAsString( int __rank ) {
        if (__rank != 0){
            return ranks[__rank];
        }//End of if statement
        return ranks2[__rank];
    }//End of rankAsString class

    Card(short suit, short rank)
    {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;    
    }//End of Card Initializer

    public @Override String toString()
    {
        if(suit == 5){
            return "Joker";
        }//End of if statement that calls jokers
        if(rank == 0){
            return "Joker";
        }
        return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];              
    }//End of toString method

    public short getRank() {
         return rank;
    }//End of getRank method

    public short getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }//End of getSuit method
}//End of Card
```

And finally, here is the `deck()` class:

```
package dummyrummy;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class deck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
    deck()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        int index_1, index_2;
        Random generator = new Random();
        Card temp;

       short jokerSuit=5;
       short jokerRank = 0;
           cards.add(new Card(jokerSuit, jokerRank));
           cards.add(new Card(jokerSuit,jokerRank));
        for (short suit=0; suit<=3; suit++)
        {
             for (short rank=0; rank<=12; rank++)
             {
                  cards.add(new Card(suit,rank));
             }
        }//End of for-loop       
        int deckSize = 54;             
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            index_1 = generator.nextInt( cards.size() );
            index_2 = generator.nextInt( cards.size() );
            temp = cards.get( index_2 );                    
            cards.set( index_2 , cards.get( index_1 ) );
            cards.set( index_1, temp );
        }//End of for-loop
    }//End of deck()
    public Card drawFromDeck()
    {
    /*
     * This method removes the top card of the already shuffled deck.          
     * The next step to take with this class is put the drawn card into another
     *     array that represents a players hand.  
     * This will take two arrays, and must be called depending on what player   'drawsFromDeck'.
     */        
        return cards.remove( 0 );
    }//End of drawFromDeck()
    public int getTotalCards()
    {
        return cards.size();   
    }//End of getTotalCards()
}//End of class deck
```

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate any help that may come. I would also be more than happy to provide my other code, if necessary.

**EDIT:** I have added the class and package above.

Comment: There is not enough information here. The one thing I would is that please stick to Java naming conventions - classes should be in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Note that your question don't seem to have anything to do with particular program, but rather how to call methods of classes. You may want to change your sample to reflect just that (2 small classes with main and whatever `PlayerHands` constructor without much implementation).

Comment: what kind of method you are trying to call in your main()? Can you give more information.

Comment: "I am strictly working with Array Lists for all of the code" - No, you are not. You are working with Arrays of `Card`, not `ArrayList`s. In what file do you declare that code?

Comment: @T.Woody Can you add the code in which you try to call the `PlayerHands` constructor?

Comment: @keshlam What you say is not right. It is "package visible" if it does not have a modifier.

Comment: Keshlam, I tried to make the constructor public, but had the same error as before. The hint asked to create a class PlayerHands(dummyrummy.Deck, int) in the main. I have just finished trying to do this, but there is now a problem with using 
    `private Card[] playerOneCards`
and
    `private Card[] playerTwoCards`
.

Comment: ... Right. I'm going to sign off now; I'm clearly typing in my sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PlayerHands(deck, int)` is a constructor. Therefore you have to call it like this (in class `DummyRummy`):

```
new PlayerHands(testDeck, round);
```

And since i guess you want to work with the instance you created, you should save the reference to a variable:

```
PlayerHands playerHands = new PlayerHands(testDeck, round);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am quite embarrassed by making such a simple mistake. I may have more questions once I get to the GUI, haha. I am very grateful for the help everyone has provided!

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerHands(deck d, int round)` is not a method, it is a constructor.

To correctly get the two hands, you can use this code:

```
    ...
    int round = 1;
    PlayerHands playerHands = new PlayerHands(testDeck, round); //This creates a new instance of the PlayerHands class
    //access the players' hands like this:
    Card[] player1Hand = playerHands.playerOneCards; //sets "player1Hand" to the "Card[] playerOneCards" contained in "playerHands"
    Card[] player2Hand = playerHands.playertwoCards; //sets "player2Hand" to the "Card[] playerTwoCards" contained in "playerHands"

    }//End of arguments
}//End of DummyRummy class
```